# Rails boolean attribute defaulting to true in tests but shouldn't be

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing

On Rails 4.

Just added an `approved?` attribute to my article model with `default: false`

When I went to write an integration test I noticed that in the testing environment the `approved?` was defaulting to true. To counteract this behavior, I manually added `approved: false` to the fixtures (articles.yml) file, but feel I shouldn't have to do this.

Is this the correct behavior? Still new to testing.

Here is what my migration looks like:

```
class AddApprovalToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :articles, :approved, :boolean, default: false
    add_column :articles, :approved_at, :datetime
    add_column :articles, :approved_by, :string
  end
end
```

Here is my test that is not passing:

```
test "mod article should not be approved as default" do
  log_in_as(@mod)
  article = articles(:mod_article)
  assert_not article.approved?
  get edit_article_path(article)
  assert_template 'articles/edit'
end
```

and my fixtures:

```
mod_article:
  title: is it bad to be a mod
  content: no I don't think so
  created_at: <%= 10.days.ago %>
  updated_at: <%= 10.days.ago %>
  user: mod
```

If I add `approved: false` to the above fixture, it will pass.

I recently finished Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, in which we added an `admin?` boolean to the user model. In that case, the fixtures knew to default the value to false.

Thanks for the help, let me know if you need any other specific code of mine.

Comment: just added test and fixture @WesFoster

Comment: `$ bundle exec rake db:migrate` ?

Comment: Nope, `rake db:migrate:status` shows me that everything is up! This is so weird. @7stud

Comment: Test has nothing to do with migration. If you are using fixtures, data in fixture is your test database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Fixtures is a fancy word for sample data. Fixtures allow you to
>   populate your testing database with predefined data before your tests
>   run. Fixtures are database independent written in YAML. 
>   [Quoted from Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures)

If you use fixtures, your database is not going to be tested. So default value set in migration don't matter.

Comment: Ok makes sense. I just can't figure out why in the Rails Tutorial, we didn't set the `user.admin?` to false inside of the fixture. Somehow it knew to default it to false, hence the only user that was an admin is the one where we explicitly set it to true. @EdmundLee

Comment: Can you provide a link? Btw, you can refer to this for more details about fixtures: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html. If you are not stuck with test unit or minitest, Rspec mock is something you can look at. @Kathan